# Visual Studio SSIS: Changing Default NameSpace in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I cannot seem to find a solution: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Can I change this `GUID` looking `Default namespace`?

Here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can do it.

There is a property called `ScriptProjectName` that is only available through the Expression Editor. Setting it can change the project name and the namespace in the script. You need to set the expression and save the package prior to editing the script.

You can [follow this article](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2008/04/30/renaming-the-script-project-in-ssis-2008/) for more details.

Comment: Hi my friend: I did look at that, the Expression Editor does not have such value in visual studio 2013. I cannot find it.